# Find and delete line in .htaccess file

Tags: command-line, centos, regex

I am trying to figure out how could possible a command do search and delete line from .htaccess file . the following line is the line i want to search and delete

```
RedirectMatch \.(dynamiccontent|pl|plx|perl|cgi|php|php4|php4|php6|php3|shtml)$ http://server.linux.com/cgi-sys/movingpage.cgi
```

Note that this line have special characters

This is the command to find the code

```
find /home*/*/public_html/ -mindepth 1 -iname "\.htaccess" -type f -exec grep -Hi "RedirectMatch*" '{}' \;
```

But this is only find not find and delete the line in .htaccess file

How can i modify the command to find and delete the line that i mention ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
grep -iv "RedirectMatch*" $file>tmp
mv tmp $file
done < <(find /home*/*/public_html/ -mindepth 1 -iname "\.htaccess" -type f -print0)
rm tmp
```

The output of the find command gets used by [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) in the `while` loop, as `$file`. Then `grep -vi $file` returns every line in `$file` that *doesn't* match (ignoring case). It writes that to a temp file called **tmp**, and then copies it over the original **.htaccess** files. For safety you could add this extra line before the `mv` command:

```
mv "$file" "$file".old
```

This will rename the original htaccess files to .htaccess.old, in case something is borked.

Comment: i got the following errors 
line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
line 4: `done < <(find /home*/*/public_html/ -mindepth 1 -iname "\.htaccess" -type f print0 );'

Comment: Damn, there was a typo in the find command. Should be `-print0` see how you go now.

Comment: i got two errors each error in one line

Comment: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: line 4: `done < <(find /home*/*/public_html/ -mindepth 1 -iname "\.htaccess" -type f -print0)'